# Fourier transform of a a function f(t) times a rational function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Suppose we know the Fourier transform of $f(t)$.

**Is it possible to compute the Fourier transform of $\frac{f(t)}{(t^2-a^2)^2}$ in terms of the Fourier transform of f(t) ?**

The rational function $\frac{1}{(t^2-a^2)^2}$ can be decomposed as $\frac{1}{4 a^3 (a+t)}+\frac{1}{4 a^2 (a+t)^2}-\frac{1}{4 a^3 (t-a)}+\frac{1}{4 a^2 (t-a)^2}$ but I'm not sure it is possible in general to find $\mathscr{F}\Big[\frac{f(t)}{a\pm t}\Big]$ or $\mathscr{F}\Big[\frac{f(t)}{(a \pm t)^2}\Big]$ in terms of the Fourier transform of $f(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

The Fourier Transform of $g(t)=1/(t\pm |a|)$ is

$$\mathscr{F}\{g\}(\omega)=i\pi \text{sgn}(\omega)e^{\mp \omega |a|}$$

Then, using the convolution theorem reveals

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{fg\}(\omega)&=\mathscr{F}\{f\}*\mathscr{F}\{g\}\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\mathscr{F}\{f\}(\omega')\right)\left(i\pi \text{sgn}(\omega')e^{\mp (\omega-\omega') |a|}\right)\,d\omega'\\\\
&=i\pi e^{\mp \omega|a|}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\mathscr{F}\{f\}(\omega')\right)\left(i\pi \text{sgn}(\omega')e^{\pm \omega' |a|}\right)\,d\omega'\\\\
\end{align}$$

Is this what you sought?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The convolution theorem is indeed a possibility. Going in that direction, we should have $\mathscr{F} \Big( \frac{1}{(t^2-a^2)^2} \Big) (\omega) = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \text{sgn}(w) (\sin (a w)-a w \cos (a w))}{2 a^3}$ if we assume $a$ being a positive real, and from there get the answer to the initial question through the convolution theorem.

Comment: I was also considering developping $\frac{1}{(t^2-a^2)^2}$ into a series and then use the fact that the Fourier Transform of each $t^{2n}.f(t)$ term involves the $2n$ derivative of the Fourier Transform of $f(t)$. The answer would be then an infinite sum of these derivatives but I don't know what to do with such an infinite sum.